# GDAL raster with python error: 'NoneType' when I use gdal.Warp

Tags: qgis, python, raster, grass-7.0

I'm trying to 'north-up' a georeferenced raster in a python environment, this is the code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = gdal.Open(r"DJI_0895.TIF")
dsReprj = gdal.Warp("n0895.tif", ds, dstSRS = "EPSG:4326")
```

but nothing happens. I tried to see what's going on by adding:

```
type(dsReprj)
```

then it threw **'NoneType'**. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you also check that `ds` is correctly defined/loaded? Can you display the original image?

Comment: put `gdal.UseExceptions()` near the top, and see if you get a `RuntimeError` message

Comment: Yes, I displayed it with matplotlib and it was fine

Comment: When you say "nothing happens"... how did you determine that nothing happens?  Please be more specific.   Does the output file not exist?  Did you try to open "n0895.tif", or do a gdalinfo on it?  What do you see if you run a gdalinfo or a `GetProjection()` on the source dataset?

Comment: With 'nothing happens' I mean that there is not an output file, in this case 'n0895.tif' doesn't exist. The input tif originally has no projection, I assigned it using QGIS, but when I try to import in GRASS GIS it said the input raster is flipped or rotated. I've read that I can fix it If I use gdal.Warp, but i'm stuck.